# Loading 3rd Party dll in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, icu, azure-functions-runtime, azure-durable-functions

I am using [icu.net](https://github.com/sillsdev/icu-dotnet) in Azure Functions with the 2.1 runtime. When I build the icu dlls (`icuin59.dll`, `icuio59.dll`, `icutest59.dll`, `icutu59.dll`, `icuuc59.dll`, and `icudt59.dll`) are copied to the `../netcoreapp2.1/lib/win-x64` folder and also the `../netcoreapp2.1/bin/runtimes/win7-x64/native` folder. `icu.net.dll` is also copied to `../netcoreapp2.1/bin`.

I am running locally on Windows 10.

When my function executes I am getting:

```
[20/03/2019 16:09:14] Executed 'AnalyzeVocabulary' (Failed, Id=cb768548-dd06-4f95-b889-af244af716d1)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: AnalyzeVocabulary. icu.net: Can't load ICU library (version 0).
[20/03/2019 16:09:14] 926e7209782c408984ad827cc2744b2d: Function 'AnalyzeVocabulary (Activity)' failed with an error. Reason: System.IO.FileLoadException: Can't load ICU library (version 0)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14] File name: 'icuuc'
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at Icu.NativeMethods.LoadIcuLibrary(String libraryName)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at Icu.NativeMethods.get_IcuCommonLibHandle()
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at Icu.NativeMethods.uloc_canonicalize(String localeID, IntPtr name, Int32 nameCapacity, ErrorCode& err)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at Icu.Locale.<>c__DisplayClass44_0`1.<GetString>b__0(IntPtr ptr, Int32 length)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at Icu.NativeMethods.GetString(Func`3 lambda, Boolean isUnicodeString, Int32 initialLength)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at Icu.Locale.GetString[T](GetStringMethod`1 method, T localeId)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at Icu.Locale.Canonicalize(String localeID)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at Icu.Locale.op_Implicit(String localeId)
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at DigitalLinguistics.TextAnalytics.TextSegApiTokenizer.TextTokenizer.SegmentSentences(String sentence) in E:\DigitalLinguistics\Dev\ServerlessSentinel\DigitalLinguistics.TextAnalytics\TextTokenizer.cs:line 70
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at DigitalLinguistics.TextAnalytics.TextSegApiTokenizer.TextTokenizer.Tokenize(String sentence, String id) in E:\DigitalLinguistics\Dev\ServerlessSentinel\DigitalLinguistics.TextAnalytics\TextTokenizer.cs:line 82
[20/03/2019 16:09:14]    at DigitalLinguistics.TextAnalytics.DataStructures.Sentence.LineParse(String text, String id, TokenizerOptions tokenOpts) in E:\DigitalLinguistics\Dev\ServerlessSentinel\DigitalLinguistics.TextAnalytics\Sentence.cs:line 92
```

**NOTE** I have successfully run with these from a net core console app so I'm guessing the libraries are just not in the right folder.

Any suggestions on where the libraries need to be and how I can set up so they're deployed and published there as part of my build using VS 2017?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out from the source code in GitHub that the location has to be `../netcoreapp2.1/bin/lib`.